# If I switch my VPN country to where the website server is located should I get faster downloads?

Tags: vpn, download

As the title says, is that how it works?

If not could you explain ways of what influences download speed from certain websites? My internet speed is 180 Mbps but some websites downloads are much faster than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible* that this will make the download faster – but it's not guaranteed to.

Download speed depends on the slowest part of the whole chain. Your data goes through some 5–15 routers and connections. If one of them is particularly busy or has unusually high latency, that's what contributes to your low speed the most. So if your VPN connection (the whole "website→VPN→you") takes a different path, it could bypass the slow connection.

This could happen even if the VPN server is still in the same country as you → for example, if your ISP uses one international carrier but the VPN provider uses another, then a VPN server in your country might work better than one in the website's country, in case it's the international link that is slow.

The opposite is also possible. Paths are often asymmetric, your request might be sent through one carrier but response received through another. If that happens, then indeed a VPN server that's close to the website may help a lot.

But that's not guaranteed. Sometimes the slowest link is not in the middle but right next to you or the website. For example, if the webserver only has a 10 Mbps uplink, then it literally can't send data faster than 10 Mbps (and that's shared between visitors!), so there's almost nothing that a VPN could do to help with that. Similarly, if the website is hosted from another continent that's physically 300ms away, it's not going to become any closer through a VPN.

Comment: Is there a cmd to check the website uplink limit, and where it routes to? I used `whois` to find out where the server was, it’s in Bulgaria and I’m in the U.K, switching my VPN to Bulgaria didn’t make a difference, interestingly using several websites that find the location of the server turned up Netherlands so I also switched my VPN to that with no avail.

Comment: No, not unless you literally have admin access to the server that the website is hosted on.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the internet like a water pipe.

On a long pipe, the water will take a bit longer to first arrive, but once it does it doesn't really matter how long the pipe is, the speed of the water coming out the end depends on the narrowest section.

Of course, if you intentionally route your pipe through several different countries to reach the tap[faucet] then there's more chance of accidentally finding a bit of narrow pipe, so there is marginal gain by making as direct a route as possible… but you still don't guarantee the narrowest part of the pipe isn't on that direct route.
& lastly, there's no guarantee of how fast the tap at the other end is.

Comment: It does matter how long the pipe is, due to TCP needing to acknowledge received data before the window can move forward.

Comment: @user1686 - I think you're just introducing unnecessary complexity to an otherwise simple explanation.